# Define Array of multiple types but has only same type?

Tags: typescript

I meet a usecase, that I need to define an Array with only `string` or `number`, but can be only one type.

For example:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// but cannot be
let c = ['a', 1];
```

1. How to declare the type of this variable?

   My idea is

   ```
   let a : Array<number>|Array<string>;
   ```
2. How to cast array of only number and only string to array of number?

   ```
   let a : Array<number>|Array<string>;

   // how to cast a to b : Array<number>?
   ```

PS: This is the situation I meet

```
function f(arr: Date[] | number[]) {

    if (arr[0] instanceof Date) {
        g(arr[0]);
        g(arr[1]); // compile error in this line
        g(arr[1] as Date); // Do not use any type assertions.eslint@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions
    }
}


function g(e: Date): void {

}
```

Therefore how to avoid these error or warning and get an array of Date?

Comment: 1. is correct but it could be written as `number[] | string[]` 2. what do you mean "cast"? runtime cast?

Comment: @vr. I've added example in updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to define your own type guard. Here I've written a function `isDateArray` that checks if the given value is an array of dates.

```
function isDateArray(value: unknown): value is Date[] {
    return Array.isArray(value) && value.every((element) => element instanceof Date);
}

function f(arr: Date[] | number[]) {
    if (isDateArray(arr)) {
        arr
//      ^? Date[]
        
        g(arr[0]); // OK
        g(arr[1]); // OK
    }
}

function g(e: Date): void {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgEQIZQKYEEBO+GAngBQBuGANiNgFyLgDWYcA7mAJQOU3bIpEmHAG0AuogDeAKERzE+bFBD4kBIsQB0qdSQrVanRADJjiXrU3Zy2fGVLYq2ALbYwUIwF4AfIkcu3KGQwFCgMSGw4YCEsbE4AbmkAX2lpUEhYBERgUgxCBmFscUQAH0QwEGcAI1txIxl5ZGjSVELdMjz8TnrZRvlO6QB6Qb7EAD0Afl7R6b6Ac1zCEQAGMQTEYcQAeQBpWcaFzpEARjX4jZHd2ZSUtPBoeCQF+hicbnM4GAATKRSgA)